# Best way to tell my future self not reference a variable past a point

Tags: typescript

In line 2, I've destructured `session` and should be using `sessionWithNoId` from henceforth.

How do I ensure I don't end up accidentally using `session` after line 2?

I tried `delete session` but TS doesn't like it: `'delete' cannot be called on an identifier in strict mode.`

```
public async createOrUpdateOfflineSession(session: SessionInterface, store: Store) {
  const { id, ...sessionWithNoId } = session;
  
  const existingSession = await this.prisma.shopifyOfflineStoreSession.findUnique({
    where: { shop: session.shop },
  });

  if (existingSession) {
    await this.prisma.shopifyOfflineStoreSession.update({
      where: { shop: session.shop },
      data: { ...sessionWithNoId, sessionId: id },
      data: { ...sessionWithNoId, sessionId: id },
  } else {
    await this.prisma.shopifyOfflineStoreSession.create({
      data: {
        ...sessionWithNoId,
        sessionId: id,
        store: { connect: { id: store.id } },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: *Best way to tell my future self not reference a variable past a point* ? Don't forget?

Comment: Seems simpler to just not have the variable in the first place, instead of trying to remove it or not touch it after you use it.

Comment: @VLAZ In the example above I need the `session` argument. I'm doing something with it at one point, I guess.

Comment: You only use it to do `session.shop`. Which can be `sessionWithNoId.shop`. I don't see why you *need* `session` at all.

Comment: As always, here's my extremely cursed solution that does what you want but is frowned upon in the industry, [which uses 'asserts' to turn the type of the identifier into 'never'](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4X4w).

Comment: @hittingonme I think that is cute and I think, technically, the real answer to the question as asked. Though it would not pass code review on my team when there are cleaner ways. Academically interesting though!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the cleanest solution is to just destructure it in the function parameters instead.

```
public async createOrUpdateOfflineSession(
  { id, ...sessionWithNoId }: SessionInterface,
  store: Store
) {
  //...
}
```

Now `session` doesn't even exist in the scope of this function body.

---

> A downside is that users of the function will no longer see `session: SessionInterface` in their hints – @hittingonme

An excellent point! But it's easily fixed with a single [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) signature that represents the public interface of your function. Typically function overloads are for when a function has a few signatures, but there's nothing wrong with using when there is only one.

For example:

```
async function createOrUpdateOfflineSession(session: SessionInterface, store: Store): Promise<void>
async function createOrUpdateOfflineSession({ id, ...sessionWithNoId }: SessionInterface, store: Store): Promise<void> {
    //...
}
```

And now the visible type for the function is:

```
function createOrUpdateOfflineSession(session: SessionInterface, store: Store): Promise<void>
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQM4eAexASXGniWQG8AoZa5YAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoqacwALaExYgA1iBwB3EBQC+FCqEixEKVGBxQUlGsgwatTMFBYQ5CuBgCeIBMhgiEYXCGQItcSAHkoAVQAOdJ4QXjAwADagEOhYLgAUGJjYeEwxyQREKkgANHoGEKn5AJRMAApQOGzAiQA8AG449AB8FJY2dg62znhuHt5+gcGhEVFp8WS0dLkAdLOJsXgA6sACAHI4+HTIsqlJLoTKJBC5+poFaMVlFVW1Dc3kPNQA9E+z0+YU7hBDA0HeYZEQNE9ng4hN6EwAIwAJgAzLk+IIoEwyLJtrkJqdDMhjKZtkUKC9kAA9AD8QA)

Comment: A downside is that users of the function will no longer see `session: SessionInterface` in their hints :(

Comment: Great point, but that's an easy fix with function overloads. See my update.